# How to get column data in R

Tags: r, math

I am new to R.  I want all of the data in C column only from this table and store it in a variable called "x".  Is there a way to do this in R?

something like this "x=?????"

```
A  B   C 
1  1   1 
3  5   6 
3  1   3 
5  1   4 
6  4   2 
5  1   6
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is your table in R already or in a .txt or .csv file? Is that a subset or is that the only data you have? If it's all you have just type:

```
x <- c(1,6,3,4,2,6)
```

If it is a larger dataset that is read in from a .txt or .csv file or similar then after loading use

```
x <- LOADEDDATAFILE$C
```

You can also do the below but it's very redundant.

```
dat <- read.table(textConnection("A B   C 
1   1   1 
3   5   6 
3   1   3 
5   1   4 
6   4   2 
5   1   6"),sep="\t",header=T)

x <- dat$C
x
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
A <- c(1, 3, 3, 5, 6, 5)
B <- c(1, 5, 1, 1, 4, 1)
C <- c(1, 6, 3, 4, 2, 6)
df <- data.frame(A, B, C)
x <- df[ ,"C", drop=FALSE]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
A <- c(1, 3, 3, 5, 6, 5)
B <- c(1, 5, 1, 1, 4, 1)
C <- c(1, 6, 3, 4, 2, 6)
df <- data.frame(A, B, C)
x <- df$C
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your data is in a data.frame as MYaseen208 shows, you could also use `x <- df$C` to create a vector of your data, perhaps with a combination of `read.table()` and `textConnection()` to get the data into R if that hasn't already been addressed.

What you really need is to review the introductory manual to R here: http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-intro.html